# (jquery) Отправка формы без перезагрузки страницы/ Скрыть форму после отправки

Tags: jquery, jquery-form

Здравствуйте, не получается прикрутить форму, 
форма должна без перезагрузки страницы скрыться и допустим показать текст. 
Код ниже

```js
(function($) {

  $(function() {

    $('.rf').each(function() {
      var form = $(this),
        btn = form.find('.btn_submit');

      form.find('.rfield').addClass('empty_field');

      // Функция проверки полей формы
      function checkInput() {
        form.find('.rfield').each(function() {
          if ($(this).val() != '') {
            $(this).removeClass('empty_field');
          } else {
            $(this).addClass('empty_field');
          }
        });
      }

      // Функция подсветки незаполненных полей
      function lightEmpty() {
        form.find('.empty_field').css({
          'border-color': '#ff0000'
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
          form.find('.empty_field').removeAttr('style');
        }, 500);
      }

      setInterval(function() {
        checkInput();
        var sizeEmpty = form.find('.empty_field').size();
        if (sizeEmpty > 0) {
          if (btn.hasClass('disabled')) {
            return false
          } else {
            btn.addClass('disabled')
          }
        } else {
          btn.removeClass('disabled')
        }
      }, 500);

      btn.click(function() {

        if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
          lightEmpty();
          return false
        } else {

          form.submit();

        }
      });

    });

  });

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<label for="name">Name:*</label>
<input type="text" class="rfield" id="name" />
<input type="submit" class="btn_submit disabled" value="Отправить данные" />
```

Очень прошу помощи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так? http://jsfiddle.net/Haikson/js0s31fb/
Код приведен как подсказка, а не как решение Вашей проблемы.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  $("form[ajax=true]").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    var form_url = $(this).attr("action");
    var form_method = $(this).attr("method").toUpperCase();

    $("#loadingimg").show();

    $.ajax({
      url: form_url,
      type: form_method,
      data: form_data,
      cache: false,
      success: function(returnhtml) {
        $("#result").html(returnhtml);
        $("#loadingimg").hide();
        $(form).hide();
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        $("#loadingimg").hide();
      }
    });

  });

});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}
form span {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
input[type="text"] {
  border: 1px soild #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
#result {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ff9;
}
img#loadingimg {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"><a href="http://jsfiddle.net/Haikson/js0s31fb/" target="_blank">Пример лучше запускать на JSFiddle</a> т.к. я не знаю куда отправлять запрос на StackOverflow ))</div>

<form method="post" action="http://jsfiddle.net/echo/html/" ajax="true">


  <span>        
    <label>Message: </label>
    <input type="text" name="html" placeholder="Howdy..." />
  </span>

  <span>
    <label><img id="loadingimg" src="http://dev.cloudcell.co.uk/bin/loading.gif"/>   </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />      
  </span>

</form>
```

Comment: Да, именно так.
Правда не получилось вставить необходимый кусок кода, чтобы работало
http://jsfiddle.net/yyLj2gza/

Comment: Что то вроде этого, наверное
http://jsfiddle.net/Haikson/js0s31fb/8/

Правда jsfiddle перестал возвращать данные. Нужно еще поковырять.